# Filter Azure table with respect to current date

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Can we query the azure table in Azure Storage Explorer based on current day/date?

I am trying to fetch the records which are older than 90 days. I was able to filter based on given date, example:
 `UpdatedAtUtc lt datetime'2019-02-27T21:55:16.9605195Z'`

But I would like to query it based on current day

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by doing the following:

1. Selecting the table that you wish to query.
2. Clicking on the query button above the table display.
3. Selecting the field you wish to query on (UpdatedAtUtc)
4. Checking the box to the left of the field
5. Deleting the row below the field you have selected (X button).
6. Clicking on the value dropdown.
7. Selecting 'Custom'.
8. Enter 90 days.
9. Check the UTC radio button.
10. Click ok.
11. Click the Text Editor button (under close query and next to query builder).
12. Change ge to lt or le depending on your requirements - supported syntax is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN#supported-comparison-operators).
13. Run the query by clicking the play button.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10uF.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/heJeU.png]

Comment: I am looking for query with respect to current date, so something like now, or currentdate or today

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the suggestions mentioned by [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038661/storing-datetime-in-azure-table-storage).

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.